# Django File Access Security

Tags: django, django-permissions

I want to restrict access to all but a few selected files per a user, but if I type: /media/userdocuments/FILENAME django happily spits back the file for even users who aren't logged in. How can I integrate the permission framework to work around this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I realize that the django development server is insecure, so I guess the question is: How would I do that in a production environment with apache, lighttp, etc.

Comment: Are these files in the MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: Yes. I have MEDIA_ROOT set to a directory and MEDIA_URL set to /media/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RewriteMap` along with a script that connects to Django and verifies permissions, rewriting to a "disallowed" URL on auth failure.